# Modify SharePoint view of lookup field that can have multiple values

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2013, sharepoint-designer

I am trying SharePoint for first time. So please be nice to me. Here is what I am trying to do.

Lets say I have a List where I have values as shown below

```
Lesson        Days
----------------------
Tennis        Monday,Wednesday
Swim          Saturday
Golf          Sunday,Saturday.
```

Above Days is lookup field that can take multiple values.

How can I modify the view to look as below

```
Lesson        Days
----------------------
Tennis        Monday
              Wednesday
Swim          Saturday
Golf          Monday
              Sunday
              Saturday
```

Looks like we can code, but I have no idea how to do this.

Also it would be awsome if we have sequence number for multiple values. Something like this

```
Lesson        Days
----------------------
Tennis        1.Monday
              2.Wednesday
Swim          1.Saturday
Golf          1.Monday
              2.Sunday
              3.Saturday
```

**Edit:** Based on further search looks like I need to do Client side rendering. I found this link
[SharePoint 2013 Client Side Rendering: List Views](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/620110/SharePoint-Client-Side-Rendering-List-Views)

I am still struggling to understand this. Need much simple example on how to do this. Will appreciate any hint/help on getting this started.

Answer (score 0):

To start [this might help](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-JS-2ed3538a). Using Sample 1, changing the field name and the render function you can easily get the view version without sequence.

If you want a custom order on the days you have to change the EditForm for your days field to change the way the user inserts the days. That will be the hard part since if you do so, you have to either get the values for the lookup field by urself (using the javascript client api or rest calls) or use the default sharepoint lookupfield and customize it (I would not recommend this). To save the custom values back to the days field [this example will help](https://code.msdn.microsoft.com/office/Client-side-rendering-code-94145281) (using the *registerGetValueCallback* function)

You can include your script with a script webpart on the view page/edit page or use the jslink property on the webpart property section *miscellaneous* to include a javascript file containing the csr code.

Comment: Thank you . Looks like I have to do JS Link. Problem is either I don't know how to or I don't have access to upload JavaScript code files on your SharePoint 2013 site. I found out that can edit page and add webpart as content editor  and then add HTML code. If  I can find how how to reaplce "," with"<br> then I guess it will work.